# How to change localuser settings "user must change password at next logon" when creating user

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to create a new local user and I need to make sure the user has to change the password the next time they log in. I have found the answer for ADuser, but this user will be a localuser not an ADuser.

Comment: Check out https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/LocalAccountManagement/0.1.1/Content/Functions%5CSet-LocalUser.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You only need that module that @Graham points to if you are not on the latest version of Windows PowerShell v5x or PowerShell Code v6 and beyond, where those cmdlets are already built-in.

MS Docs:

New-LocalUser

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

```
New-LocalUser -Name "User02" -Description "Description of this account." -NoPassword
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
 New-LocalUser "User03" -Password $Password -FullName "Third User" -Description "Description of this account."
New-LocalUser -Name "MicrosoftAccount\usr name@Outlook.com" -Description "Description of this account."
```

and

Set-LocalUser

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

```
Set-LocalUser -Name "Admin07" -Description "Description of this account."
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
 $UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "User02"
 $UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
```

Read the help regarding '[-PasswordNeverExpires]'.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the WinNT provider yourself without the `LocalAccounts` module to create a local user like this:

```
$newUser      = 'Test'
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

# create a new local user using the WinNT provider
$Computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName,Computer"
$User = $Computer.Create("User", $newUser)
$User.SetPassword("abc123")
$User.SetInfo()

$User.FullName = "Test User"
$User.SetInfo()

$User.Description = "User to test WinNT"
$User.SetInfo()
```

To set the "User must change password on next logon" for a local user

```
# bind to the local user with the WinNT provider
$localUser    = 'Test'
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$user = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/$localUser,user"
if ($user.UserFlags.Value -band 65536) {        # ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    Write-Host "The password for user '$localUser' never expires"
}
elseif ($user.UserFlags.Value -band 64) {       # ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
    Write-Host "User '$localUser' is not allowed to change password"
}
elseif ($user.UserFlags.Value -band 32) {       # ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD 
    Write-Host "User '$localUser' does not require a password"
}
else {
    $user.Put("PasswordExpired", 1)
    $user.SetInfo()
}
```

<sup>See [ADS_USER_FLAG_ENUM enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_user_flag_enum)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a Powershell answer, but it works.

Use the following command:

```
net user LocalGuy /logonpasswordchg:yes
```